# Entitlements.plist key/value pair for XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios16, xcode14

I have got `User Assigned Device Name` additional entitlement approved for my bundle ID and now need to use this in XCode project. I have successfully configured this additional capability in my `AppId` in developer portal, but I can not find anyway to import it in XCode project as highlighted in the portal:

```
  Provisioning in Xcode with additional capabilities
 
  In Xcode 13 and later, once the capability is enabled for your App ID, you can configure Xcode to support automatic signing.

  In your app’s .entitlements file, add the assigned entitlement key and value pair.

  Build your app on your device.

  Xcode will detect the differences between your currently issued provisioning profile and the entitlements.plist, and request a new provisioning profile.
```

Problem is there is no `entitlements.plist` file for my target. And if I click on capabilities tab in `Signing & Capabilities` section, there is no key value pair to select for `User Assigned Device Name`. What am I supposed to do I wonder?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to locate the entitlements.plist file? I have to do the exact same this but wondering where to add the key/value pair.

Comment: @d27saurabh I had to manually create a new entitlements.plist file. It worked!